# My justified (ragged2e) text does this terribleness and I do not understand why

Tags: formatting, ragged2e

The code: (there is even a comment about some justify terribleness, but as I originally wrote this several months ago (on TexLive, now editing on Kile) I no longer remember)

```
%%%%%%%%%% Introduction Page %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\center{
\large\textit{``Y'all just left jail, are the only hope of your neighbourhood, and you're already high as a kite.''}\\~\\
Introduction:
}\\
\justify{ %TODO whats with the justify terribleness?
\normalsize  To play the game, all you need is: a few standard, six sided dice, a supply of snacks and any social lubricant substance of choice. That last part's important.} \\
\justify{Name your characters. The names could just as well be nicknames. You begin the game with no equipment, but the clothes on you - so feel free to describe them. Pick Your Number ranging from two to five as their only numerical stat. Next pick - or come up with -  two skills and one problem, each of which can only appear once in your group.}\\ %TODO  - problem?? seriously no better name?
\justify{Together with your fellow players decide what you were `canned' for. Afterwards come up with - or roll for - a description of your `hood and your best friend, perhaps two of `em (in which case they're inseparable and work pretty much as one).
} \\[40mm]
```

The text (PDFTeX) ends up looking like this, with unintended massive gaps between paragraphs:

[image: Screenshot from kile viewer.]

Even combining all \justify{} into one does not seem to solve anything. I don't even know when the gaps appeared, I was busy adding fancyhdr headers, readjusting some tables and randomly realized at some point the page looked wrong. What could be the reason?

Comment: Why are you even using `\justify`, since justifying paragraphs is the default behavior? You should post a MWE, because there's probably another command or package somewhere that causes problems.

Comment: you should either use `{\centering ...}` or `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`, but not `\center{...}`. Don't abuse \\ for line breaks.

Comment: The \center command is wrong. It will affect all the following text

Comment: you are applying `\center` and `\justify` to the whole document and resetting the baseline for your `\large` text so it is using normalsize baseline spacing. If you ever  find yourself needing `\justifying` then you should not use it and instead fix the earlier error that has disabled justification (which is the default).

Answer (score 5):

It seems you believe that the command `\center` takes an argument, but no, it doesn't.

There exists `\center` only because the `center` environment is defined, but the command should *never* be used inside a LaTeX document (it can be used in the definition of another environment, though).

There is a *declaration* form of `center` and it's called `\centering`, but, like all declarations, it should be used inside a group, so you don't need to set justification. By the way, `\justify` has the same status as `\center`, so it doesn't take an argument and should not be used in a document; the corresponding declaration form is `\justifying`.

Inputting a text is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\large\itshape
``Y'all just left jail, are the only hope of your neighbourhood, 
and you're already high as a kite.''
\end{center}

\begin{center}\large
Introduction:
\end{center}

To play the game, all you need is: a few standard, six sided dice, 
a supply of snacks and any social lubricant substance of choice. 
That last part's important.

Name your characters. The names could just as well be nicknames. 
You begin the game with no equipment, but the clothes on you --- 
so feel free to describe them. Pick Your Number ranging from two 
to five as their only numerical stat. Next pick --- or come up 
with ---  two skills and one problem, each of which can only appear 
once in your group.

Together with your fellow players decide what you were `canned' for. 
Afterwards come up with - or roll for - a description of your `hood 
and your best friend, perhaps two of `em (in which case they're 
inseparable and work pretty much as one).

\end{document}
```

I used two distinct `center` environments because the two parts are semantically distinct. You probably want to define your own structures, possibly modifying standard sectioning commands for “Introduction”, which will help to ensure uniformity across the document.

[image]

#### Some more details

When you open a `center` environment, LaTeX internally starts the basic environment `trivlist` and sets up centering of the text basically using `\centering`. The `trivlist` environment is responsible also for adding some vertical space.

The `justify` environment of `ragged2e` does similarly, with the difference that it sets up justification basically like with `\justifying`.

It's unneeded, in general, to set again justification, if declarations are properly segregated in an environment (or in a `{...}` group, but this requires some care), their effect ends with the end of the environment.

Thus, in the code above, the effect of the declarations `\large\itshape` ends with `\end{center}` as well as the effect of `\centering`. Thus the ensuing paragraphs are again set up for justification with no need to specify it.

With your code you pile up four unfinished `trivlist`s and LaTeX gets thoroughly confused.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will keep in mind from now on. Anyways, I also want to ask: Maybe it is fancyhdr stretching the contents of the page between the header and the footnote if blank space is left?

If that is the case - how would I fix that?

Comment: @NickCyvil No, `fancyhdr` shouldn't be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of said by egreg, do not use linebreaks (`\\`) in normal text. To end a paragraphs, use  just a blank line (or alternatively `\par`) and do not use `\\[40mm]` to set vertical spaces between paragraphs. Reserves this code only to the end of rows in tabular environments.

On the other hand, as far as possible, use semantic commands to tell LaTeX which is each part of the text,  not how to format it. I mean that instead of order "type the Introduction word  centered and with large font". it is better order "type Introduction as a section header" (that mean type  just `\section*{Introduction}`. If the default format for section header is not to your taste,  it is a lot easier, clearer and safer change the definition of the sections header that provide yourself several format commands for every header. The same apply if you want to make a quote, a title, or something else that plain text.

Is not clear if you have issues with right margin justification or only the vertical gaps. For the first, use babel to set the language and have correct hyphenations when needed and   `microtype` to improve de fit of the paragraphs (with moderation to avoid ugly side effects).

Finally, with respect to vertical gaps, a lot of settings of the preamble and even the contents before and after the actual page can influence the result, so a chunk of text is not enough to show properly the problem. You must make a reduced version of your document removing anything irrelevant for the issue, but leaving anything needed to run the code "as is" and obtain a PDF with this problem and only this problem. That is, a minimal working example (MWE).

Said that, gaps between paragraphs usually are caused when contents thad admit one page are not enough to fill it completely, and instead of leave all the excess of space at the bottom, it is distributed among the contents to have the same bottom margin that in the pages filled completely. This is a nice feature, but only when the excess of space is small, otherwise obtain a `\flushbottom` margin is even worse that a `\raggedbottom` margin.

The  MWE  below show an excess of space in first page due to a too big box that must jump to the next page . The space is distributed if you  use `\flushbottom`. Replacing this command by `\raggedbottom` (or just removing it)  there are only one ugly end gap, but may be also some space among paragraphs controlled by `\parskip`. However, if you remove the box, there are not ugly gaps, no matter if you use `\flushbottom` or not, because without the box, there is not need to stretch substantially the first paragraphs:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
% this produce only gaps:
\setlength{\parskip}{1em plus 1em}
\usepackage[
font={itshape,raggedright,large,centering},
indentfirst=false]{quoting}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[stretch=50,shrink=70]{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\Large\filcenter}{}{1em}{}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text after the box

\begin{document}

% this produce huge gaps only if you acthe \fbox of line 45
% \flushbottom


\begin{quoting} 
``Y'all just left jail, are the only hope of your neighbourhood, 
and you're already high as a kite.''
\end{quoting}

\section{Introduction:}

To play the game, all you need is: a few standard, six sided dice, 
a supply of snacks and any social lubricant substance of choice. 
That last part's important.

Name your characters. The names could just as well be nicknames. 
You begin the game with no equipment, but the clothes on you --- 
so feel free to describe them. Pick Your Number ranging from two 
to five as their only numerical stat. Next pick --- or come up 
with ---  two skills and one problem, each of which can only appear 
once in your group.

Together with your fellow players decide what you were `canned' for. 
Afterwards come up with - or roll for - a description of your `hood 
and your best friend, perhaps two of `em (in which case they're 
inseparable and work pretty much as one).

% box that cause one/several horrible gaps
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[b][.7\textheight][c]{1cm}    foo \end{minipage}}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```